# Does Reserve with Google (Google Maps) have restricitons on the type of businesses which can use the service?

Tags: google-maps

According to their [website](https://www.google.com/maps/reserve/), Reserve with Google promotes Dining, Events, Fitness, and Beauty businesses to use their services. I understand this is mostly a marketing page, and being such, am wondering if Google restricts business types from using this service.

I'm specifically working with a few companies in home improvement services (solar, roofing, etc).